# How uncheck others when check one in jQuery Mobile Controlgroup?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

My goal is to uncheck others when check one of the checkbox item. here is the code which is not working with jquery mobile 1.4.2 ...

JavaScript:

```
$('input.answer').on('change', function() {
    $('input.answer').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend for="0-0">Uncheck others when check one of the items</legend>
    <label for="0-0-4">one</label>
    <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-4" id="0-0-4" value="4">
    <label for="0-0-3">two</label>
    <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-3" id="0-0-3" value="3">
    <label for="0-0-2">three</label>
    <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-2" id="0-0-2" value="2">
    <label for="0-0-1">four</label>
    <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-1" id="0-0-1" value="1">
    <label for="0-0-0">five</label>
    <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-0" id="0-0-0" value="0">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jquery UI, just add the checkboxradio function...

```
$('input.answer').not(this).prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Have a nice day

Comment: while your answer still works, i just added another method to do that... :)

Answer (score 2):

Because jQuery Mobile adds its own style to each `Checkbox` - and also to the whole `Controlgroup` as well - You should invoke the `refresh` method of the  `Controlgroup` which contains your changed element. Please note, you should add your event listener inside the `pagecreate` event.

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-one", function() {
  $('input.answer').on('change', function() {
    
    $('input.answer').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    $(this).closest("fieldset").controlgroup("refresh"); // add this line
    
    /* Display the result */
    var result = "";
    $("input.answer").each(function(index) {
      var caption = $(this).parent().find("label").text();
      var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
      result += caption + ":" + checked + "  ";
    });
    $(this).closest("fieldset").find("legend").html(result);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-one" data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <form>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
          <legend for="0-0">Uncheck others when check one of the items</legend>
          <label for="0-0-4">one</label>
          <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-4" id="0-0-4" value="4">
          <label for="0-0-3">two</label>
          <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-3" id="0-0-3" value="3">
          <label for="0-0-2">three</label>
          <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-2" id="0-0-2" value="2">
          <label for="0-0-1">four</label>
          <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-1" id="0-0-1" value="1">
          <label for="0-0-0">five</label>
          <input class="answer answer-num-6" type="checkbox" name="0-0-0" id="0-0-0" value="0">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```